# Add calculated virtual property to each field with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to add a calculated properties to each field of my DTO.

For example my POJO looks like this:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserInfoDto {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String secondLastName;

}
```

The resulting json looks like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "foo",
    "lastName": "bar",
    "secondLastName": "foobar"
}
```

My target is to inform the caller of my API about specific properties of each field (i.e "editable")
And I would like it to look something like this:

```
{
    "firstName": {
        "editable": false,
        "value": "foo"
    },
    "lastName": {
        "editable": false,
        "value": "bar"
    },
    "secondLastName": {
        "editable": true,
        "value": "foobar"
    }
}
```

Currently I've changed the DTO class to look like so:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserInfoClientDto {

    private Field<String> firstName;
    private Field<String> lastName;
    private Field<String> secondLastName;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class Field<T> {
    @Builder.Default
    private boolean editable = true;
    private T value;
    
}
```

But this way it is a lot of work to maintain. I use a "toUserInfoDto" function that do some ugly code like this:

```
userInfoClientDto.getFirstName().setEditable(isFirstNameEditable);
userInfoClientDto.getLastName().setEditable(isLastNameEditable);
```

Can anyone explain of a better approach to achieve what I need?

Comment: There are other, less cumbersome approaches to this sort of thing, like JSON Schema.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own annotation named `@Field` with attribute `editable`, then create a Custom Serializer named `FieldSerializer` (see e.g. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)) that uses the annotation attribute.

They would be used like this:

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = FieldSerializer.class)
public class UserInfoClientDto {

    @Field(editable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Field(editable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Field(editable = true)
    private String secondLastName;

}
```

Since you only asked for a better approach, not a full solution, I'll leave the actual writing of the Custom Serializer to you.